# What happens to a sell order that doesn't have enough bid matches on it's ask price?

Tags: trading, stock-markets, bid-ask

A stock has a bid of 100.00 for 500 shares. I issued a sell order for 1000 shares of the same stock for 100.00.

What will happen? Will the sell order wait until there's 500 shares available at 100.00 or will it sell to the next available bid?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you mean by "for 100.00". Are you talking about an order with a limit price of $100?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 possibilities:

1. No transaction will happen until the bid volume at $100 meets or exceeds 1000 shares.  This will happen if you placed a "Do Not Reduce" limit sell order.
2. You'll sell 500 shares to the waiting buyer, and wait for a new buyer willing to pay $100 each for shares.  This will happen if you placed a limit sell order without specifying "Do Not Reduce".
3. You'll sell 500 shares to the waiting buyer and 500 shares to waiting buyers at lower prices.  This will happen if you placed a market sell order.